# PHP Simple HTML DOM not finding element though whole document

Tags: php, domdocument, simple-html-dom

I am trying to pull data out of a table from Pro-Football Reference

The table is in the bottom section after  tag OFFENSE TOTALS

here is my code:

```
$url = ("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/drive_finder.cgi?request=1&year_min=".$season."&year_max=".$season."&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=".$week."&week_num_max=".$week."&start_event%5B%5D=Downs&start_event%5B%5D=Interception&start_event%5B%5D=Punt&start_event%5B%5D=Blocked+FG&start_event%5B%5D=Missed+FG&start_event%5B%5D=Fumble&start_event%5B%5D=Muffed+Punt&start_event%5B%5D=Blocked+Punt&start_event%5B%5D=Kickoff&start_event%5B%5D=Onside+Kick&start_event%5B%5D=Own+Kickoff&start_event%5B%5D=Muffed+Kickoff&end_event%5B%5D=Touchdown&end_event%5B%5D=Field+Goal&end_event%5B%5D=Missed+FG&end_event%5B%5D=Fumble&end_event%5B%5D=Interception&end_event%5B%5D=Downs&end_event%5B%5D=Punt&end_event%5B%5D=Blocked+Punt&end_event%5B%5D=Blocked+FG&end_event%5B%5D=Safety&end_event%5B%5D=End+of+Half&end_event%5B%5D=End+of+Game&exclude_kneels=1&drive_st_gtlt=lt&drive_st_own_opp=Own&drive_end_gtlt=lt&drive_end_own_opp=Opp&drive_end_yds=20&drive_num_gtlt=gt&start_quarter%5B%5D=1&start_quarter%5B%5D=2&start_quarter%5B%5D=3&start_quarter%5B%5D=4&start_quarter%5B%5D=5&end_quarter%5B%5D=1&end_quarter%5B%5D=2&end_quarter%5B%5D=3&end_quarter%5B%5D=4&end_quarter%5B%5D=5&tr_gtlt=lt&minutes=15&seconds=0&order_by=game_date");

$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('div#div_offense_totals') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

nothing will return

if you do this

```
foreach($html->find('div.table_outer_container') as $e)
     echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

you will get results but they are the results from the top of the page even though the same div and class are in the bottom section.

Totally baffled on this one.

Real URL

```
https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/drive_finder.cgi?request=1&year_min=2014&year_max=2014&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=1&week_num_max=1&start_event%5B%5D=Downs&start_event%5B%5D=Interception&start_event%5B%5D=Punt&start_event%5B%5D=Blocked+FG&start_event%5B%5D=Missed+FG&start_event%5B%5D=Fumble&start_event%5B%5D=Muffed+Punt&start_event%5B%5D=Blocked+Punt&start_event%5B%5D=Kickoff&start_event%5B%5D=Onside+Kick&start_event%5B%5D=Own+Kickoff&start_event%5B%5D=Muffed+Kickoff&end_event%5B%5D=Touchdown&end_event%5B%5D=Field+Goal&end_event%5B%5D=Missed+FG&end_event%5B%5D=Fumble&end_event%5B%5D=Interception&end_event%5B%5D=Downs&end_event%5B%5D=Punt&end_event%5B%5D=Blocked+Punt&end_event%5B%5D=Blocked+FG&end_event%5B%5D=Safety&end_event%5B%5D=End+of+Half&end_event%5B%5D=End+of+Game&exclude_kneels=1&drive_st_gtlt=lt&drive_st_own_opp=Own&drive_end_gtlt=lt&drive_end_own_opp=Opp&drive_end_yds=20&drive_num_gtlt=gt&start_quarter%5B%5D=1&start_quarter%5B%5D=2&start_quarter%5B%5D=3&start_quarter%5B%5D=4&start_quarter%5B%5D=5&end_quarter%5B%5D=1&end_quarter%5B%5D=2&end_quarter%5B%5D=3&end_quarter%5B%5D=4&end_quarter%5B%5D=5&tr_gtlt=lt&minutes=15&seconds=0&order_by=game_date
```

Comment: I did `var_dump($html)`, and it looks like Simple HTML DOM is having trouble parsing the URL. Try using `DOMDocument` instead.

Comment: Please provide a real URL so we can check the actual HTML. The one in you provided is built on multiple variables which are not available in your code sample.

Comment: so sorry about that. Here you go

Comment: Are you sure, that simple_html_dom will read the content of comments, parse it's content as normal elements and not just cut them off? Because your element `#div_offense_totals` is commented out, which can do troubles.

Comment: There is a huge block of code that is commented out but if you look below that in the view source you will find div_offense_totals

Comment: Here is part of the problem which i don't understand. If you do a "view source" on the real url i have listed above, and you do a search on 'div_offense_totals", it will be part of the commented out code. Yet go to the real url listed above and right mouse click on the 'TM' column and select "Inspect Element" - you will find div_offense_totals uncommitted. This is probably why both the simple dom and dom document are not finding this ID tag. Thoughts on this?